# Application Repeatedly Downloads Automatically

Tags: applications, vpn, macos

I have a laptop given to me by a university (currently not employed by them). I've been trying to delete a VPN application (Global Protect) that was mandatory to login to university websites. It appears in the menubar and so is always running. To delete the application I have to delete the executable file by going into the package contents of the application, then go to the activity monitor, kill the related process, and then finally delete the rest of the package contents. However, in an hour or two the application just automatically re-downloads! I have no idea what is responsible for this, how can I find out?

Comment: You likely have MDM software installed by the university.  You need to get them to unenroll the device.

Comment: is there any way to check if that is the case?

Comment: It depends on the tool.  There’s Microsoft Intune, JAMF, and the Apple Configurator.  That’s just some popular ones. Your best bet is to contact the university and confirm that the device is unenrolled and the organizational Apple ID is disassociated.

Comment: Ok I looked on System Preferences -> profiles and I do indeed have MDM software.

Comment: Is there any sneaky sneaky way to delete it

Comment: Nope.  That you can’t do.  Even wiping the drive will have no effect.